# Bitcoin transfer by putty

Tags: bitcoind

I installed Bitcoin core, a vps server and have access to putty being Linux operating system .. how can trensfer all Bitcoin account in altcont?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. What do you mean with "how can trensfer all Bitcoin account in altcont?' Do you want to trade your Bitcoin for an altcoin?

Comment: I mean that I can connect remotely core Bitcoin? , Or EXIT command Bitcoin that can transfer from my account into another account on VPS?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Your question isn't the clearest, but I'll try to make sense of it.

PuTTY is an SSH client. It's a way for you to communicate to your server. You can't send bitcoin **through** the connection.

But what you can do is open up core through PuTTY, and if you want to send bitcoin to the VPS wallet (I highly advise against this, your VPS provider has access to your private keys), get your recieve address and send your bitcoin to that address. If you want to send to another wallet. Get the recieving address from there and send the bitcoin to that address through your core.

I'm not sure about "altcont", but I'm guessing you mean altcoin. It is not possible to deposit an altcoin into a bitcoin wallet, but what you can do is deposit that altcoin onto an exchange (using the method above), exchanging it for bitcoin, then withdrawing it to your bitcoin wallet (again the method above)